# How to fix this error in Python ( AttributeError: 'Int64Index' object has no attribute 'dayofweek'

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to use pandas' get_dummies function to get dummies for day of the week

```
days_of_week = pd.get_dummies(df.index.dayofweek, prefix='weekday',
drop_first=True)
```

I got this error: `AttributeError: 'Int64Index' object has no attribute 'dayofweek'`

Could anyone help please?

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that your index isn't a DateTimeIndex. The 'dayofweek' attribute is not available for integer indexes. You first need to convert your index to DateTime and apply this code. If you have dates in a standard format, you can do it like this:

```
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)
```